# Much more (of something)

Tags: parts-of-speech

> People are concerned about crime because there is **much more** of it.

What Parts of Speech are **much** and **more** here?

Comment: What do you think? Please show us you've done some research, what you turned up, and what you're still unsure about.

Answer (score -1):

"More" is a comparative adjective modifying "crime". "Much" is a superlative adverb modifying "more". Together "much more" form a phrasal comparative adjective.

Comment: I wonder why it matters. Yes, in your analysis, "much more" goes like this: much more crime. :) Where crime is a mass noun. Like coffee, Ha ha.

Comment: **pronoun** [comparative of ‘many’ and ‘much’] https://www.oed.com/oed2/00151364

Comment: @GJC What is your point? Posting that entire entry from the OED is **not helpful at all**. What David says is right. You can also see it as: *more*, a noun, and *more* as an adjective because of the prepositional phrase: of it.

Comment: See in that definition in the OED: 2. a. Something that is more; a greater quantity, amount, degree, etc. Then: b: followed by a partitive **of**.

Comment: I wish that any downvoters would leave a comment indicting what they think is wrong with this answer. In the absence of a comment, I cannot improve the answer, others cannot use the reasons to write better answers, and readers have no idea why someone objects to the answer. Such a downvote seems pointless.

Comment: @DavidSiegel It could be because "much" isn't superlative.